# Targeting multiple input fields with using same name

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of

```
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="50">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="10">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="90">
```

I also have a input field

```
<input type="text" name="Add" value="">
```

I want

1. each price[] input field to have their own Addition Button next to it that will get the value from that specific price[] input field
2. add the value from the Add input field to it
3. update the value of that specific price[] input field in the end

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not give them all unique IDs?

Comment: I can update only one input field at a time without distinct IDs so I am kinda lost.

Comment: You could iterate over the childNodes property of the parent if all of your input tags were in a form or div.

Comment: @ManishPradhan posting a question on stackoverflow is generally for when you have tried everything you can think of, googled for it, tried all of those as well, and still cannot solve the problem. your question sounds like you've been presented with a problem and want the community here to do all of that work for you.

Comment: @jbabey This is what I could do with my very limited JS knowledge

                function addNumbers()
                {
                  var dis = parseInt(doc..getElementById("dis").value);
                        var val1 = parseInt(doc...getElementById("value1").value);
                        doc..getElementById("value1").value = val1 - ((dis/100) * val1);
                }
      
  Dicont<input type="text" id="dis"><br>
        Price <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1" value="100"/><input type="button" name="Sumbit" value="Click" onclick="javascript:addNumbers()"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to iterate through the price[]-boxes for adding buttons right to them and set the value from price[] to the button, do it like this

```
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="100">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="50">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="10">
<input type="text" name="price[]" value="90">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name="price[]"]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).after('<button class="additionButton" price="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).val()+'</button>');
    });
    //click
    $(".additionButton").on('click',function() {
        //original price, set on load
        alert($(this).attr('price'));
        //price in the input-field before the button (could be changed, think this is the idea)
        alert($(this).prev('input').val());
    });
});
</script>
```

for the rest, i am not sure what you mean, "Add" has no value and you seriously want some kind of calculation? But try yourself, here was at least the iteration.

Comment: Thanks, Thats at least a start. The Add is meant to be filled by the user so it is empty. now I need to figure out how to update just that text field when its button is clicked.

Comment: take note that this solution uses jQuery, which is not tagged on the question.

Comment: Thanks I did note that. I am starting to think, there is not solution without Jquery.

Comment: sorry about jquery, Was honestly not aware :-( Has added a click handler for the buttons, and a price-attribute to the button. In the click handler example of getting "original" price and the new entered in the corresponding input field.